# ionic build android doesn't do anything

Tags: windows-7, ionic-framework

I am trying to set up ionic in my Windows 7 machine. I follow the steps here http://ionicframework.com/docs/guide/installation.html.

When i do the step, ionic add platform android, it does nothing. ionic platform android tries to download cordova-android but not sure if its fine. Below are my console logs. Can someone help me how to solve this issues.

C:\inv-mob\todo>ionic platform android
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/cordova-android/3.6.3
npm
C:\inv-mob\todo>ionic build android

C:\inv-mob\todo>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

reinstalling the android sdk worked.